# Counting Graph Isomorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am self studying graph theory and was wondering: is there a simple way to count/compute the number of subgraphs G that are isomorphic to another graph (say, G')?

For instance, if G = the complete graph "K_10" with 10 vertices, and G' = Hypercube H_3 with 3 vertices

Or, if G = Hypercube "H_4" with 4 vertices, and G' = Complete biparite graph "K_1, 3".

Comment: I think the total number of ways to count would be P(10, 3) for the first case?

Comment: Do you mean "Hypercube $H_3$ with $2^3$ vertices"?

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a complete graph, and the vertices of $G'$ are labelled, it's easy, because you can use any one-to-one mapping of the vertices of $G'$ into the vertices of $G$.  If the vertices of $G'$ are not labelled, you'll want to divide by the number of automorphisms of $G'$.

Comment: Let's assume that $G$ has $x$ vertices and $G'$ $y$ vertices. Is it possible to count explicitly how many one-to-one mappings are there of the vertices of $G'$ into the vertices of $G$?

Comment: The number of one-to-one mappings of $[1,\ldots,y]$ to $[1,\ldots,x]$ (where $x \ge y$) is $x (x-1) \ldots (x-y+1) = x!/(x-y)!$.